# (Swift) How can you assign specific number of items for separate iCarousels?

Tags: ios, swift, icarousel

This iCarousel: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

He has a 'multiple carousels' example project that is in Obj-C, however the number of items is random.

In the number of item function, I am unable to explicitly state which iCarousel I wish to assign a number of items too. They always seem to load in a random order. I have 6 BTW.

Here are pictures of the outlets.

[image: StoryBoard connections]

[image: ViewController connection]

The rest of my code is identical to yours. 
It cannon reference the carouselView in the numberOfItems function.

My views: [image: views]

Data source: [image: data source]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iCarousel instance is passed as a parameter to the `numberOfItemsInCarousel` function.  You can use this to determine which carousel is requesting the number of items in each case.  Something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, iCarouselDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var carousel1: iCarousel!
    @IBOutelt weak var carousel2: iCarousel!

    var carousel1Items = [String]()
    var carousel2Items = [String]()

    func numberOfItemsInCarousel(carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {

        var numberOfItems = 0

        switch carousel {
            case self.carousel1:
                numberOfItems = self.carousel1Items.count

            case self.carousel2:
                numberOfItems = self.carousel2Items.count

            default:
                print("Unknown carousel!")
        }

        return numberOfItems
    }
}
```

Comment: I have included everything in your answer. However, "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". This happens on the case line.

Comment: My code assumes that you are using a storyboard and have assigned carousel instances to the IBOutlets.  If you aren't using storyboards and are creating the carousels some other way you need to ensure you set the properties (`carousel1` etc) when you do so.

Comment: I have used IBOutlets to a storyboard. Here is something to consider maybe. In the carousel function: if carousel == carouselView1 {} would work fine. However, that would not work in NumberOfItems. Is there something I can put in a print() to see what is present?

Comment: My guess is that your outlets are nil either because you haven't linked them or you haven't created the view controller from the storyboard. A switch/case statement is the same as nested if statements. You can set a breakpoint on the function and step through to see what is happening

Comment: I added my outlets and connections. Still don't know why I can't reference them like you did in numberOfItems.

Comment: Have you used the debugger - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/UsingtheDebugger.html ?  What is nil?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124414/discussion-between-paulw11-and-james).